# Prove that $a^{N-1} = 1 \mod N$ with $\gcd(a,N) = 1$ is equivalent to $N$ is square free and $p-1|N-1$ for all primes $p|N$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $a^{N-1} = 1 \mod N$ with $\gcd(a,N) = 1$ is equivalent to $N$ is square free and $p-1|N-1$ for all primes $p|N$.

i tried from left to right by looking at primitive roots. So suppose $N = p^e * m$, where $p$ are odd primes and $e \geq 2$. we see that if $r$ is a primitive root:

$r^{\phi(p^e)} = 1 \mod p^e$.

Because $\gcd(p^e,m) = 1$ we see for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$a^{N-1} = 1 \mod N$.

So particulary $r^{N-1} = 1 \mod N$. So with this info:

$r^{N-1} = 1 \mod p^e$.

But then $\phi(p^e) | N-1$ so we see:

$p^e - p^{e-1} = (p^e * m -1) * k$. for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This is the part where i am stuck. How do i go further, and how do i prove this for N which have an even prime divisor?

Kees

Comment: Note that $p^e-p^{e-1}$ can divide $N-1$ only for $e=1$; if $e>1$, then you get $p|(N-1)$, which is not possible because $p|N$.

Comment: of course thanks! Do you see why $r^{N-1} = 1 \mod N$, because my argument is false i noticed :)

Comment: Since we have $a^{N-1}=1(mod N)$ for all $a<N$ with $gcd(A,n)=1$, we can take $a$ to be $r (mod p^e)$ such that $ord(r)=\phi(p^e)$ and $(r,N)=1$.

Comment: to be honest, i dont understand why we can find such n. It looks like you are using the chinese remainder theorem but i don't see how....

Comment: For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number.

Comment: See [Korselt's Criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KorseltsCriterion.html) and [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1464360/236182).