# Question related to pseudoprimes and Carmichael numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

We know by Fermat's little theorem that if $m$ is a prime then for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then 
$$
n^m \equiv n (mod \ m).
$$
I was wondering if there was a composite $m$ that satisfies this condition?
(Maybe this condition is equivalent to being a Carmichael number, but I wasn't sure...)
Thank you!

Comment: To finish the argument, we use the Korselt Criterion. I have written out an answer. The system frowns on long comment strings, so I will delete mine and suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to prove two things: (i) if $m$ is composite and  $a^m\equiv a\pmod{m}$ for all $a$, then $m$ is a Carmichael number and (ii) If $m$ is a Carmichael number, then $a^m\equiv a \pmod{m}$ for all $a$.

Proving (i) is easy. For suppose that $a^m\equiv a\pmod{m}$ for all $a$. In particular, suppose that $a$ is relatively prime to $m$. Then by division we get that $a^{m-1}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Since $m$ is composite, it follows that $m$ is a Carmichael number.

Proving (ii) is harder. We need the fact that if $m$ is a Carmichael number, then $m$ is square-free. Proofs can be found fairly easily by searching, so we omit the proof.

Thus $m$ can be expressed as a product $p_1p_2\cdots p_t$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes.

Suppose first that $a$ is not divisible by $p_i$. Then $a^{p_i-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$.  By the Korselt Criterion (please see Wikipedia), we have $p_i-1$ divides $m-1$. It follows that $a^{m-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$, and therefore $a^m\equiv a \pmod{p_i}$.

Suppose next that $a$ is divisible by $p_i$. Then $a^m\equiv a\pmod{p_i}$, since both are congruent to $0$.

We have shown that $a^m\equiv a\pmod{p_i}$ for all the primes $p_1$ to $p_t$. Since the $p_i$ are distinct, it follows that $a^m\equiv a\pmod{m}$.

Comment: I finally get it now. Thank you very much for your patience and all the help. Greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: You are welcome. I may return to the question, to do it with less machinery.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. It's a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) by definition. $561$ is the smallest Carmichael number.

Comment: For $m$ a Carmichael number, by the definition the congruence holds true if $(n,m)=1$. But I am not sure if this is the case if $(n,m)>1$. Could you possibly explain more? Thank you!